# How to share state between react client components with a parent server component?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, react-server-components

In my next.js app I have a page with two components: `A` and `B`.

```
// page.tsx

import A from './A'
import B from './B'

const Page = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <A />
      <B />
    </div>
  )
}

export default Page
```

```
// A.tsx

'use client';

import { useState } from 'react'

const A = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

  return (
    <div>
      <p>you clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>click me</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default A
```

```
// B.tsx

'use client';

import { useState } from 'react'

const B = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

  return (
    <div>
      <p>you clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>click me</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default B
```

Let's assume that I want to render `Page` statically on the server. However, I also would like to implement state on the client side. What is the best way to synchronize the state of `A` and `B` while keeping `Page` as a server component?

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the context API for that. You can render your context provider it in a [client component](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#using-context-in-client-components) and inject it in your page:

```js
// page.tsx
// ...

const Page = () => {
  return (
    <MyProvider>
      <A />
      <B />
    </MyProvider>
  )
}

// ...
```

The context can look something like this:

```js
// CountProvider.tsx

"use client";

interface CountContextType {
  count: number;
  setCount: Dispatch<SetStateAction<number>>;
}

export const CountContext = createContext<CountContextType>({
  count: 0,
  setCount: () => {},
});

export default function CountProvider({children}: {children: React.ReactNode}) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState<number>(0);
  return (
    <CountContext.Provider value={{ count, setCount }}>
      {children}
    </CountContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Finally, you can access and modify the same context count from your child components, effectively sharing the state. For example, in the component `A`, instead of using:

```js
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
```

You can use:

```js
const {count, setCount} = useContext(CountContext);
```

Comment: Great answer! Thanks!  I'd just comment that Dispatch & SetStateAction are standard React imports.